# Tween Background in and then dynamic images - AS3 Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addeventlistener, tween

I have a method that takes a few paramerters and dynamicly adds three images to the stage it also adds a background image to the three images.

I am trying to figure out the following: How can I tween in the background movieclip and on complete tween in the three dynamic movieClips? Can I have a function within a function that shares the same variables?

Something like the following:

```
public function addImages(BackGround:String,Image1:String,Image2:String,Image3:String):void
        {


           var symbol_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(BackGround);
           var image1_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image1);
           var image2_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image2);
           var image3_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image3);

                  var main_bg = new symbol_class();
                  var image_1 = new image1_class();
                  var image_2 = new image2_class();
                  var image_3 = new image3_class();

          main_box.addChild(main_bg);

                  var BGTween:Tween = new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
                  BGTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

                   //WHEN BACKGROUND TWEEN IS COMPLETE NOW ADD THE OTHER IMAGES AND FADE THEM IN.
                  function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
                    BGTween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

               main_box.addChild(image_1);
                     var image_1_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_1, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                main_box.addChild(image_2);
                   var image_2_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_2, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                main_box.addChild(image_3);
                    var image_3_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_3, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                    }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close there, you can't define a function within a function quite like that, but you can do the following:

```
       public function addImages(BackGround:String,Image1:String,Image2:String,Image3:String):void
       {


              var symbol_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(BackGround);
              var image1_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image1);
              var image2_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image2);
              var image3_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(Image3);

              var main_bg = new symbol_class();
              var image_1 = new image1_class();
              var image_2 = new image2_class();
              var image_3 = new image3_class();

              main_box.addChild(main_bg);

              var BGTween:Tween = new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
              BGTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, function(e:TweenEvent) {
                    //WHEN BACKGROUND TWEEN IS COMPLETE NOW ADD THE OTHER IMAGES AND FADE THEM IN.
                    (e.target as EventDispatcher).removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

                    main_box.addChild(image_1);
                     var image_1_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_1, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                    main_box.addChild(image_2);
                   var image_2_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_2, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);

                    main_box.addChild(image_3);
                    var image_3_tween:Tween = new Tween(image_3, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
              });
      }
```

This is called a **closure** because it's an **anonymous function** that references values outside its immediate scope. You can read more about them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). Also note how the **removeEventListener** has changed, this is the way to remove an anonymous function because no name reference exists for it.

Comment: Thanks I actually got a few things from your response. Thanks! +1 checked.

Answer (score 0):

use TweenLite?
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite

usage:

```
TweenLite.to(bgObject, timeToFade,{alpha:0, onComplete:addThreeImages});

public function addThreeImages():void
{
//here you can add your images
}
```